# Solving linear equations represented as a string

Tags: algorithm, expression-trees

I'm given a string `2*x + 5 - (3*x-2)=x + 5` and I need to solve for `x`. My thought process is that I'd convert it to an expression tree, something like,

```
          =
        /  \
       -    +
      /\    /\
     +  -   x  5
    /\  /\ 
   *  5 * 2
  /\   /\
 2  x  3 x
```

But how do I actually reduce the tree from here? Any other ideas?

Comment: you usually reduce such trees with the distributivity and commutivity axioms

Comment: C or C++ ? Solutions will most likely be very different depending on which language you are actually using.

Comment: Either, preferably c++

Comment: @PaulR not really - pattern mathcing vs something else will vary, but the concept is the same

Comment: @PaulR. Won't make much of a difference. You can write object oriented even in C.

Comment: @user3125280: concepts, yes, but for any practical solution the options will be very different.

Comment: @PaulR i don't consider this a concrete solutino type question, but we can agree to disagree. AST manipulation is hard and silly in both c and c++, imho. Use haskell! :)

Comment: @user3125280 "I don't consider this a concrete solution type question" - then it shouldn't have **either** the [tag:c] or [tag:c++] tags. [tag:algorithm] is popular enough to stand alone, although [tag:expression-trees] and [tag:data-structures] are probably also be applicable. For non-language-specific questions, [tag:pseudocode] or [tag:language-agnostic] can be used, but I don't think either is particularly applicable here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to reduce it using axioms from algebra

```
a * (b + c) -> (a * b) + (a * c)
```

This is done by checking the types of each node in the pass tree. Once the thing is fully expanded into terms, you can then check they are actually linear, etc.

The values in the tree will be either variables or numbers. It isn't very neat to represent these as classes inheriting from some AbstractTreeNode class however, because cplusplus doesn't have multiple dispatch. So it is better to do it the 'c' way.

```
enum NodeType {
    Number,
    Variable,
    Addition //to represent the + and *
}

struct Node {
    NodeType type;
    //union {char*,  int, Node*[2]} //psuedo code, but you need
    //something kind of like this for the 
    //variable name ("x") and numerical value
    //and the children
}
```

Now you can query they types of a node and its children using switch case.

As I said earlier - c++ idiomatic code would use virtual functions but lack the necessary multiple dispatch to solve this cleanly. (You would need to store the type anyway)

Then you group terms, etc and solve the equation.

You can have rules to normalise the tree, for example

```
constant + variable -> variable + constant
```

Would put x always on the left of a term. Then `x * 2 + x * 4` could be simplified more easily

```
var * constant + var * constant -> (sum of constants) * var
```

In your example...

First, simplify the '=' by moving the terms (as per the rule above)

The right hand side will be -1 * (x + 5), becoming -1 * x + -1 * 5. The left hand side will be harder - consider replacing a - b with a + -1 * b.

Eventually,

2x + 5 + -3x + 2 + -x + -5 = 0

Then you can group terms ever which way you want. (By scanning along, etc)

(2 + -3 + -1) x + 5 + 2 + -5 = 0

Sum them up and when you have mx + c, solve it.

Comment: could you explain how it would happen in the example I've specified?

Comment: @Aks is this at all helpful? if have done this, for example, to reduce a first order logic formula to clausal normal form, which is a very similar process. Could I make this more helpful somehow?

Comment: yep, I get how the axioms will apply to the tree, but I'm doubtful about how I would actually go about doing that

Comment: @Aks i don't really have the time to do it for you. I will add a little code though :)

Comment: @Aks if the question is about the actual implementation of said tree, then it should be tagged c/c++. If this is the case, please change the question to reflect this. -oh an the dispatch stuff is my opinion, feel free to ignore that part

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a first order equation, check all the leaves on each side. On each side, have two bins: one to add up all the leaves containing a multiple of X and one for all the leaves containing a multiples of a constant. Either add to a bin or multiply each bin as you step up the tree along each branch from the leaves. You will end up with something that is conceptually like

```
a*x + b = c*x + d
```

At that point, you can just solve

```
x = (d - b) / (a - c)
```

Comment: I'm thinking, I'd do a postorder traversal of the expression tree, for each x encountered, if the parent operator is a *, store the other leaf as x's count, else store 1 as x's count. does this make sense?

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Just make sure you also increment the constant term if both leaves are a constant.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the equation can reduce to f(x) = 0, and f(x) = a * x + b.

You can transform all the leaves in expression tree to f(x), for example : 2 -> 0 * x + 2, 3 * x -> 3 * x + 0, then you can do arithmetic operations of f(x) in expression tree. finally solve the equation f(x) = 0.

If the function is much more complicated than polynomial, you can do a binary search on x, and using the expression tree to calculate the left and right side of equation.