# Solve string linear equation

Tags: julia

I have a linear equation in string format for example something like this:

```
equation = "2 * x + 1 = 17"
```

what would be the best approach to solving the equation for `x`?

Comment: My approach would be to search for existing packages: https://juliapackages.com/c/symbolic-computation I'm not sure if this is the best approach or how to objectively measure which approach is better.

Comment: I am sure there are several ways of doing this, but from top of my head you can perhaps use ```split(equation, '=')``` to get left hand side and right hand side of the equations and then you can either loop through the elements to find x. 

I personally would implement something like:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038250/solving-linear-equations-represented-as-a-string



----------

Comment: yes, a tree should be the go to solution but I was wondering if julia didn't have something like that inbuilt or if I can somehow exploit Meta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
julia> using Roots

julia> f(x) = eval(Meta.parse("2 * $x + 1 - 17"))
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> find_zero(f, 5)
8.0
```

(Thanks to my friend [Elias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19201370/elias-carvalho), I learned this way to solve such problems).

Comment: This is still, IMO, a step back from MATLAB's `solve(str2sym('2 * x + 1 = 17)')`. It was even simpler in older versions as just `solve('2 * x + 1 = 17')`. As much as I love Julia, I still miss the simplicity of MATLAB's Symbolic Math Toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

As another option, using `Symbolics.jl`:

```
julia> using Symbolics

julia> equation = "2 * x + 1 = 17"
"2 * x + 1 = 17"

julia> @variables x
1-element Vector{Num}:
 x

julia> eqn = eval(Meta.parse(replace(equation, "=" => "~")))
1 + 2x ~ 17

julia> Symbolics.solve_for(eqn, x)
8.0
```

(not sure which equations Symbolics knows how to solve)

Comment: This is better than the other answer in two ways; you don't have to manually modify the string expression, and using symbolic `solve_for` seems more natural here. I wish `Symbolics` was able to recognize that expression in the first place, though.

Comment: @AboAmmar Unfortunately it seems to solve only linear equations now. But as symbolic math is unlimited, there is hope this method will improve with Symbolics.jl